# Number of unique values per column by group

Tags: python, pandas

Consider the following dataframe:

```
      A      B  E
0   bar    one  1
1   bar  three  1
2  flux    six  1
3  flux  three  2
4   foo   five  2
5   foo    one  1
6   foo    two  1
7   foo    two  2
```

I would like to find, for each value of `A`, the number of unique values in the other columns.

1. I thought the following would do it:

   ```
   df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.nunique())
   ```

   but I get an error:

   ```
   AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'nunique'
   ```
2. I also tried with:

   ```
   df.groupby('A').nunique()
   ```

   but I also got the error:

   ```
   AttributeError: 'DataFrameGroupBy' object has no attribute 'nunique'
   ```
3. Finally I tried with:

   ```
   df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.apply(lambda y: y.nunique()))
   ```

   which returns:

   ```
         A  B  E
   A            
   bar   1  2  1
   flux  1  2  2
   foo   1  3  2
   ```

   and seems to be correct. Strangely though, it also returns the column `A` in the result. Why?

Comment: FWIW, your method #3 works for me (I get `2 1 1` for the `E` column), and it's what I would have suggested.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `DataFrame` object doesn't have `nunique`, only `Series` do. You have to pick out which column you want to apply `nunique()` on. You can do this with a simple dot operator:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.B.nunique())
```

will print:

```
A
bar     2
flux    2
foo     3
```

And doing:

```
df.groupby('A').apply(lambda x: x.E.nunique())
```

will print:

```
A
bar     1
flux    2
foo     2
```

Alternatively you can do this with one function call using:

```
df.groupby('A').aggregate({'B': lambda x: x.nunique(), 'E': lambda x: x.nunique()})
```

which will print:

```
      B  E
A
bar   2  1
flux  2  2
foo   3  2
```

To answer your question about why your recursive lambda prints the `A` column as well, it's because when you do a `groupby`/`apply` operation, you're now iterating through three `DataFrame` objects. Each `DataFrame` object is a sub-`DataFrame` of the original. Applying an operation to that will apply it to each `Series`. There are three `Series` per `DataFrame` you're applying the `nunique()` operator to.

The first `Series` being evaluated on each `DataFrame` is the `A` `Series`, and since you've done a `groupby` on `A`, you know that in each `DataFrame`, there is only one unique value in the `A` `Series`. This explains why you're ultimately given an `A` result column with all `1`'s.

Comment: Thanks -- I was hoping to avoid iterating through the dataframe, but there may be no other choice.

Answer (score 3):

I encountered the same problem.
Upgrading pandas to the latest version solved the problem for me.

```
df.groupby('A').nunique()
```

The above code did not work for me in Pandas version 0.19.2.
I upgraded it to Pandas version 0.21.1 and it worked.

You can check the version using the following code:

```
print('Pandas version ' + pd.__version__)
```