# Pandas GroupBy object behaving differently when passed through custom function

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I was doing the following test with data set

```
df = pandas.DataFrame({'A' : ['foo', 'bar', 'foo','bar','foo', 'bar','foo', 'foo'],'B' : ['one', 'one', 'two','three','two', 'two', 'one', 'three'],'C' : np.random.randn(8),'D' : np.random.randn(8)})
df = pandas.concat([df, df])
df.reset_index(inplace= True, drop = True)
df['dates'] = pandas.date_range('1/1/2000', periods = df.shape[0])
grouped = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index = False)
```

now I wrote a custom function like

```
def knowType(x):
    print(type(x))
```

and applied on the "grouped" groupby object like this

```
grouped.agg(knowType)
```

I got the stdout like this:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

But when I changed the function like this

```
def knowType(x):
    print(type(x))
    uniq = x.unique()
    print(",".join(uniq))
```

and called the this similarly

```
grouped.agg(knowType)
```

I got the following error:

```
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>
<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-41-5e12be303545> in <module>()
----> 1 grouped.agg(knowType)

/home/srinath/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   3595     @Appender(SelectionMixin._agg_doc)
   3596     def aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs):
-> 3597         return super(DataFrameGroupBy, self).aggregate(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   3598 
   3599     agg = aggregate

/home/srinath/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in aggregate(self, arg, *args, **kwargs)
   3120             # grouper specific aggregations
   3121             if self.grouper.nkeys > 1:
-> 3122                 return self._python_agg_general(arg, *args, **kwargs)
   3123             else:
   3124 

/home/srinath/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs)
    781 
    782         if len(output) == 0:
--> 783             return self._python_apply_general(f)
    784 
    785         if self.grouper._filter_empty_groups:

/home/srinath/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in _python_apply_general(self, f)
    653     def _python_apply_general(self, f):
    654         keys, values, mutated = self.grouper.apply(f, self._selected_obj,
--> 655                                                    self.axis)
    656 
    657         return self._wrap_applied_output(

/home/srinath/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in apply(self, f, data, axis)
   1525             # group might be modified
   1526             group_axes = _get_axes(group)
-> 1527             res = f(group)
   1528             if not _is_indexed_like(res, group_axes):
   1529                 mutated = True

/home/srinath/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/groupby.py in <lambda>(x)
    769     def _python_agg_general(self, func, *args, **kwargs):
    770         func = self._is_builtin_func(func)
--> 771         f = lambda x: func(x, *args, **kwargs)
    772 
    773         # iterate through "columns" ex exclusions to populate output dict

<ipython-input-40-e3b0c59fb896> in knowType(x)
     16 def knowType(x):
     17     print(type(x))
---> 18     uniq = x.unique()
     19     print(",".join(uniq))

/home/srinath/anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages/pandas/core/generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   2670             if name in self._info_axis:
   2671                 return self[name]
-> 2672             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   2673 
   2674     def __setattr__(self, name, value):

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'unique'
```

What's interesting is stdout is saying the type is DataFrame. Why is that?
I went through [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002926/number-of-unique-values-per-column-by-group) SO but couldn't get what is happening there. Can anybody help me?
Thank you

Comment: `pandas.unique(x)`. `unique` is a function of `pandas`, not `DataFrame`

Comment: series has a unique function too. When I try to write the function like this
`def knowType(x):
    print(type(x))
    uniq = x.unique()`
then the stdout is a pandas.Series object. I have a doubt that why suddenly the type(x) was pandas.DataFrame object when I introduced the 
`print(",".join(uniq))`

Comment: Maybe `agg` return `df`, because `agg` create dataframe from Series - it nicer show `apply` - `def knowType(x):
    print(type(x))
    print (x)` and `grouped = df.groupby(['A','B'], as_index = False).apply(knowType)`

Comment: Apply sends a DataFrame object to the function. My question was why is there is a sudden change of behaviour of the type of series object when I called the join on it. Though the type was there previous to the join function call