# Count number of unique occurrences in a dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I would like to divide the number of sales by the number of sales opportunities in order to get average sales by opportunities.

Here is an example dataframe with mixed types:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Opportunity':['AB122','AB122','AB123', 'AB124'],
           'Quantity': [2, 3, 4, 1],
           'Member': ["AACC", "AACC", "AACC", 'DDEE']})


print (df)
  Opportunity  Quantity Member
0       AB122         2   AACC
1       AB122         3   AACC
2       AB123         4   AACC
3       AB124         1   DDEE
```

I was able to get the sum of the sales with this one

```
df.pivot_table('Quantity', 'Member', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

But if I do the same for the Opportunity, I only get the Opportunity names glued together. Also, the duplicate opportunities are still included.

```
df.pivot_table('Opportunity','Member', aggfunc=np.sum)
```

What I need instead is that the opportunities are counted, but only the unique ones (AACC should only have 2 opportunities). The outcome of the counting should be:

```
print (df2)
AACC 2
DDEE 1
```

So then I could get the average member sales by dividing the sales quantity by number of opportunities:

```
print (df3)
AACC 4.5 
DDEE 1
```

Note on the calculation. AACC gets 2 as 9 divided by 2 is 4.5, DDEE gets 1 as 1 divided by 1 is 1.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Number of unique values per column by group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27002926/number-of-unique-values-per-column-by-group)

Comment: `df.pivot_table('Opportunity','Member', aggfunc='count')
`?

Comment: or `df.groupby('Member')['Opportunity'].nunique()`?

Comment: Your output is wrong. `AAC` count is `3` And thus the average sale is also wrong

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`groupby.apply`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.apply.html) here to get your average sale, so we don't have to do groupby twice:

```
df.groupby('Member').apply(lambda x: x['Quantity'].sum() / x['Opportunity'].nunique())

Member
AACC    4.5
DDEE    1.0
dtype: float64
```

To get the column name use [`reset_index`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html):

```
df.groupby('Member').apply(lambda x: x['Quantity'].sum() / x['Opportunity'].nunique())\
    .reset_index(name='avg sale')

  Member  avg sale
0   AACC       4.5
1   DDEE       1.0
```

Comment: Your calculation gives me the avg sales of all opportunities. The dublicate opportunities are not taken off. AACC should be 3, not 2.6 Sorry if I was not clear in the my text "What I need instead is that the opportunities are counted, but only the unique ones"

Comment: You changed the dataframe, If I run the same code, it gives the correct output. See my edit.

Comment: I corrected by question as there was a mistake in the output. The result should actually not be 3 but 4.5 as you did you delete the duplicate AB122, AB122, AB123. Only one AB122 should be calculated, hence 9 should be divided by 2 and not 3. Sorry for my confusion here.

Comment: I see, edited my answer accordingly to get your desired result. @ManuH, using `nunique` now instead of `count`

Answer (score 1):

```
df.groupby('Member').apply(lambda x: x.Quantity.sum())
```

which will group the df by Member column and then sum the Quantity per each group for example :

```
  Member Opportunity  Quantity
0   AACC       AB122         1
1   AACC       AB122         3
2   DDDD       AB123         4
3   AACC       AB124         1
```

will produce :
    Member
    AACC    5
    DDDD    4
    dtype: int64

Comment: No need for apply here: `df.groupby('Member')['Quantity'].sum()`